# .Net Core Logging Dependency Injection - resolve ILogger / ILogger`1 - what does the tick mean? Resolve type possible?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection, ilogger

I'm working with a .Net Core 3.1 XUnit project.

I create a SerivceCollection and call the AddLogging extension method. Then I can create an ILogger instance with the LoggerFactory / ILoggerFactory and when I debug, I can my ServiceCollection has a ServiceDescriptor for this type:

```
Lifetime = Singleton, ServiceType = {Name = "ILogger`1" FullName = "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1"}, ImplementationType = {Name = "Logger`1" FullName = "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1"}
```

I'm curious what that tick mark means in the type name and if it's possible to resolve an ILogger instance without using the LoggerFactory.

Here are a couple failed attempts at resolving ILogger`1. The last call to CreateLogger works.

```
[Fact]
        public void AddLogging_RegistersILogger()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging();

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger1 = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>(); // logger == null

            try
            {
                var logger2 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<>));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[T]' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TCategoryName]'
            }

            try
            {
                var loggerTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ILogger)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == "ILogger`1");
                var loggerType = loggerTypes.First();
                var logger3 = serviceProvider.GetService(loggerType);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // Implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[T]' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TCategoryName]'
            }

            var logger4 = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<DependencyInjectionTests>();

            Assert.NotNull(logger4);
        }
```

Comment: normally associated with generic types

Comment: I think you can also mock the logger, if need to inject in some service to resolve like

var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<SomeService>>();
var someService = new SomeService(logger);

Answer (score 3):

The tick on `` "ILogger`1" `` means its a generic type, i.e. `ILogger<CategoryName>`

You can inject `ILogger<T>` for any generic type. The generic type is used to set the category name in a convenient manner, e.g. `ILogger<Controller>` will have `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller"` category name

The common practice is for each class to have a logger with the category name of the class, e.g. a class named`MyService` will have a logger `ILogger<MyService>`

You can either inject `ILogger<T>` or use `ILoggerFactory`:

- Injecting `ILogger<MyService>` is equivalent to calling `loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>()` or `loggerFactory.CreateLogger("<namespace_of_my_service>.MyService")`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by implemented NLog using the following steps in asp.net core

```
https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part3/

Nuget:
1. NLog.Config
2. NLog.Extensions.Logging

Logging

functionality added to software so someone can get insight into the software

Logging as targets and rules.
```

nlog.config  (change property to copy always)

```
1. the logfile name creates a file in the logs directory
2. debug is wrote to the logfile target

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="internallog.txt">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${startupdir}\logs\${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

startup.cs

```
1. load the nlog.config
2. ConfigureLoggerService is part of the static class called Service Extensions.  Its job is to create a singleton task for the LoggerManager

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            LogManager.LoadConfiguration(@"nlog.config");
            Configuration = configuration;
            //_env = env;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.ConfigureLoggerService();
    }
```

serviceExtensions.cs

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureLoggerService(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerManager, LoggerManager>();
        }
    }
```

LoggerManager.cs

```
1. use the dependency injected Logger for nLog to post based on type.

 public class LoggerManager : ILoggerManager
    {
        private static ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public void LogDebug(string message)
        {
            logger.Debug(message);
        }
        public void LogError(string message)
        {
            logger.Error(message);
        }
        public void LogInfo(string message)
        {
            logger.Info(message);
        }
        public void LogWarn(string message)
        {
            logger.Warn(message);
        }
    }
```